# WSO2 API Manager - Sample PizzaShackAPI is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 API Manager.  I followed the Quick Start Guide to learn  by deploying sample PizzaShackAPI.

```
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide
```

As I click "Try It Out!", I am not getting the correct response as mentioned in the guide.

I am getting the below response and there is no log in the console initially.

Response Code

0

Response Headers

{
"error": "no response from server"
}

After I added Self Signed Certificate in Firefox as Add Exception, I am getting the below error in the console,

```
[2017-03-01 15:06:51,309] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: An established connection was aborted by the software in your
 host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.receiveEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.java:371)
```

I guess it may be a certificate configuration issue.  Please help me to resolve this issue.

I tried with creating my own API. Facing the same issue.

Comment: You should subscribe to the API by creating an Application or using the Default application before invoking the API. Have you done that before "try-it-out" ?

Comment: Yes. I have done that.  I subscribed and generated token to invoke the API.

Comment: in the try it window you can find a curl command, use it in a command line console and test your url again. add -k at the end

Answer (score 0):

Error message "error": "no response from server" on API console is mostly due to CORS error.  Could you please check  your browser console and see the error there, Most likely you will see error related to cors.

**Note**: these changes are not advised for production environment, for production environment you want to provide all relevant information instead of allow all (*)

To allow all headers and origin edit *repository/conf/api-manager.xml* and change values for following:

```
<Access-Control-Allow-Headers>*</Access-Control-Allow-Headers>
<Access-Control-Allow-Origin>*</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>
```

Second change to allow all  host name and avoid any certificate host name validation.
 Edit */repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml* and un comment HostnameVerifier and change value to AllowAll.

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

Restart API Manager and test again.