# debug rest call in wso2 api manager

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am connecting rest api call with wso2 api manager. I followed the steps from wso2 [site](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+and+Publish+an+API)

I am able to connect with rest api on my computer but following same procedure on another computer returns "Error: No Response from Server"

I had also configured the files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529124/wso2-api-manager-sample-pizzashackapi-is-not-working#answer-42540467)

Does anybody knows how to debug what is going wrong there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable wirelogs and headers in API Manager to analyze the request response flow.

1. Open log4j.properties file in  /repository/conf directory.
2. Uncomment the following loggers.

   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
3. Save the changes and Restart the Server
4. Invoke the API.

Regarding your "Error: No Response from Server" response, other than the CORS issue, this can occur due to browser certificate issue as well.

Therefore, first check whether you can invoke the same API using a rest client like curl,

if yes 
go to your browser, accept the certificate for the gateway URL and try out invoking the API again.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i am able to get response from curl by adding insecure option, curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 56dc08ee-f5ff-371f-8c35-7038d27d64b1' 'https://192.168.3.57:8243/updatedVersion/1.0/updatedVersion' --insecure.